# 'Object' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'ImageProvider<Object>'

Tags: firebase, flutter

I get following error when using Circle Avatar:

The argument type 'Object' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'ImageProvider'

This is the code:

```
CircleAvatar(
   backgroundImage: snapshot.data['imageUrl'] == "" 
    ? AssetImage('assets/img.png')
    : NetworkImage(snapshot.data['imageUrl']));
```

[image: Picture of the code and error]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is currently an open issue on GitHub with dart 2.12.

As a workaround you can cast the object

```
AssetImage('assets/img.png') as ImageProvider,
```